# Cpanel sql backup failed

Tags: innodb, mysql, cpanel, myisam

My hosting provider makes daily automated full site backups, like the ones which you can make using Cpanel. After requesting one of these files I noticed that the `mysql` folder contains files with all of my database names, but all of them have a size of 0 KB.

I've been provided with some logs from the export script:

```
ERROR: Failed to dump one or more databases

warn [pkgacct] db_1: mysqldump: unknown variable 'innodb_file_per_table=1'

warn [pkgacct] db_1: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(0 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database db_1
db_wp2warn [pkgacct] db_wp2: mysqldump: unknown variable 'innodb_file_per_table=1'

warn [pkgacct] db_wp2: mysqldump: unknown variable 'innodb_file_per_table=1'

db_wp2.dev_commentmeta
note     : The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
```

I'm not even using any innodb tables (all of them are MyISAM) and I don't understand what `mysqldump: unknown variable 'innodb_file_per_table=1'` refers to. Any ideas how to fix this without compromising data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

This line is most likely in your `/etc/my.cnf` file.  Remove that line or comment it out and restart mysql, this should resolve it.